# pcieport 0000:00:1c.4: AER: device [8086:9d14] error status/mask=00001000/00002000

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless

I know, that somethin should be around Wifi adapter, but I am clueless.
Sometimes my wifi connection lives long, sometimes is unstable and network should be restarted every 2 minutes

i can see only following
**pcieport 0000:00:1c.4: AER:   device [8086:9d14] error status/mask=00001000/00002000**

**Hardware** XPS 9360
**BIOS** 2.13.0

================================
sudo ethtool -i wlp58s0

```
driver: ath10k_pci
version: 5.4.0-51-generic
firmware-version: WLAN.RM.4.4.1.c3-00123
expansion-rom-version: 
bus-info: 0000:3a:00.0
supports-statistics: yes
supports-test: no
supports-eeprom-access: no
supports-register-dump: no
supports-priv-flags: no
```

================================

```
Linux XPS 5.4.0-51-generic #56-Ubuntu SMP Mon Oct 5 14:28:49 UTC 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
LSB Version:    core-11.1.0ubuntu2-noarch:printing-11.1.0ubuntu2-noarch:security-11.1.0ubuntu2-noarch
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS
Release:    20.04
Codename:   focal
```

================================

Comment: I am experiencing similar issue using Dell Latitude laptop with TB15 USB-C dock. Only difference is that I am connected by Ethernet to my dock. However the same problem. This issue started on my side approximately 5 days ago

Answer (score 0):

Seems like kernel issue. Old kernel 5.4.0-52-generic did the same issues to me.
I have upgraded my Ubuntu 20.04.1 to kernel `5.6.0-1032-oem` and dmesg log is clear for now

```
sudo apt install linux-headers-oem-20.04 linux-oem-20.04 --fix-missing
```